# How can I write SQL in Oracle in my case?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

So, Here are the tables-

```
create table person (
id number,
name varchar2(50)
);

create table injury_place (
id number,
place varchar2(50)
);

create table person_injuryPlace_map (
person_id number,
injury_id number
);

insert into person values (1, 'Adam');
insert into person values (2, 'Lohan');
insert into person values (3, 'Mary');
insert into person values (4, 'John');
insert into person values (5, 'Sam');


insert into injury_place values (1, 'kitchen');
insert into injury_place values (2, 'Washroom');
insert into injury_place values (3, 'Rooftop');
insert into injury_place values (4, 'Garden');


insert into person_injuryPlace_map values (1, 2);
insert into person_injuryPlace_map values (2, 3);
insert into person_injuryPlace_map values (1, 4);
insert into person_injuryPlace_map values (3, 2);
insert into person_injuryPlace_map values (4, 4);
insert into person_injuryPlace_map values (5, 2);
insert into person_injuryPlace_map values (1, 1);
```

Here, table `person_injuryPlace_map` will just map the both other tables.

How I wanted to show data is -

```
Kitchen   Pct      Washroom   Pct     Rooftop   Pct     Garden   Pct
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1         14.29%   3          42.86%   1        14.29%   2        28.57%
```

Here, the value of Kitchen, Washroom, Rooftop, Garden column is the total incidents happened. Pct columns will show the percentage of the total count.

How can I do this in Oracle SQL?

Comment: Good to see someone providing the create and insert statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the standard **PIVOT** query.

Depending on your **Oracle database version**, you could do it in two ways:

Using **PIVOT** for **version 11g** and up:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2  FROM
  3    (SELECT c.place place,
  4      row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY c.place ORDER BY NULL) cnt,
  5      (row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY c.place ORDER BY NULL)/
  6      COUNT(place) OVER(ORDER BY NULL))*100 pct
  7    FROM person_injuryPlace_map A
  8    JOIN person b
  9    ON(A.person_id = b.ID)
 10    JOIN injury_place c
 11    ON(A.injury_id = c.ID)
 12    ORDER BY c.place
 13    ) PIVOT (MAX(cnt),
 14             MAX(pct) pct
 15             FOR (place) IN ('kitchen' AS kitchen,
 16                             'Washroom' AS Washroom,
 17                             'Rooftop' AS Rooftop,
 18                             'Garden' AS Garden));

   KITCHEN KITCHEN_PCT   WASHROOM WASHROOM_PCT    ROOFTOP ROOFTOP_PCT     GARDEN GARDEN_PCT
---------- ----------- ---------- ------------ ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------
         1  14.2857143          3   42.8571429          1  14.2857143          2 28.5714286
```

Using **MAX** and **DECODE** for **version 10g** and before:

```
SQL> SELECT MAX(DECODE(t.place,'kitchen',cnt)) Kitchen ,
  2    MAX(DECODE(t.place,'kitchen',pct)) Pct ,
  3    MAX(DECODE(t.place,'Washroom',cnt)) Washroom ,
  4    MAX(DECODE(t.place,'Washroom',pct)) Pct ,
  5    MAX(DECODE(t.place,'Rooftop',cnt)) Rooftop ,
  6    MAX(DECODE(t.place,'Rooftop',pct)) Pct ,
  7    MAX(DECODE(t.place,'Garden',cnt)) Garden ,
  8    MAX(DECODE(t.place,'Garden',pct)) Pct
  9  FROM
 10    (SELECT b.ID bid,
 11      b.NAME NAME,
 12      c.ID cid,
 13      c.place place,
 14      row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY c.place ORDER BY NULL) cnt,
 15      ROUND((row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY c.place ORDER BY NULL)/
 16      COUNT(place) OVER(ORDER BY NULL))*100, 2) pct
 17    FROM person_injuryPlace_map A
 18    JOIN person b
 19    ON(A.person_id = b.ID)
 20    JOIN injury_place c
 21    ON(A.injury_id = c.ID)
 22    ORDER BY c.place
 23    ) t;

   KITCHEN        PCT   WASHROOM        PCT    ROOFTOP        PCT     GARDEN        PCT
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1      14.29          3      42.86          1      14.29          2      28.57
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Oracle 11g or above you can use pivot function for your required output.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT id
        ,place
        ,round((
                cnt / sum(cnt) OVER (
                    ORDER BY NULL
                    )
                ) * 100, 2) AS pct
    FROM (
        SELECT a.id
            ,a.place
            ,count(a.id) AS cnt
        FROM injury_place a
        JOIN person_injuryPlace_map b ON a.id = b.injury_id
        GROUP BY a.id
            ,a.place
        )
    )
pivot(max(id) , max(pct) pct FOR place IN (
            'kitchen' AS kitchen
            ,'Washroom' Washroom
            ,'Rooftop' Rooftop
            ,'Garden' Garden
            ))
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to first take the count and pct in a subquery then use max+decode function to summarize both of them in the required fashion
Check if the below query helps:

```
SELECT Max(Decode(i.place,'Kitchen',cnt)) AS "Kitchecn"
     , Max(Decode(i.place,'Kitchen',pct)) AS "Pct"
     , Max(Decode(i.place,'Washroom',cnt)) AS "Washroom"
     , Max(Decode(i.place,'Washroom',pct)) AS "Pct"
     , Max(Decode(i.place,'Rooftop',cnt)) AS "Rooftop"
     , Max(Decode(i.place,'Rooftop',pct)) AS "Pct"
     , Max(Decode(i.place,'Garden',cnt)) AS "Garden"
     , Max(Decode(i.place,'Garden',pct)) AS "Pct"
  FROM (SELECT i.place
             , Count(pim.injury_id) AS cnt
             , (Count(pim.injury_id)*100/(SELECT Count(*) FROM person_injuryPlace_map)) AS pct 
          FROM person_injuryPlace_map pim
         INNER JOIN injury_place i ON i.id = pim.injury_id
         GROUP BY i.place)
```

Comment: You have a syntax error using column alias. using single quotes makes it a string, not an alias.

Comment: Thanks both. Corrected the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like the following -

```
select a."kitchen"
, round((100/"Total")*a."kitchen") "Pct"
, a."Garden"
, round((100/"Total")*a."Garden") "Pct"
, a."Washroom"
, round((100/"Total")*a."Washroom") "Pct"
, a."Rooftop"
, round((100/"Total")*a."Rooftop") "Pct"
from 
(

select 
sum(decode(ip.place, 'kitchen', 1, 0)) "kitchen"
, sum(decode(ip.place, 'Garden', 1, 0)) "Garden"
, sum(decode(ip.place, 'Washroom', 1, 0)) "Washroom"
, sum(decode(ip.place, 'Rooftop', 1, 0)) "Rooftop"
, sum(decode(ip.place, 'kitchen', 1, 0))
+ sum(decode(ip.place, 'Garden', 1, 0))
+ sum(decode(ip.place, 'Washroom', 1, 0)) 
+ sum(decode(ip.place, 'Rooftop', 1, 0)) "Total"
from 
person p
join person_injuryPlace_map pim on pim.person_id = p.id
join injury_place ip on ip.id = pim.injury_id
) a
```